# Challenge - escape this text, safely yet accurately

Tags: php, jquery, escaping

This is a follow up to my last question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148820/escaping-output-safely-for-both-html-and-input-fields) The answer posted there actually does not work. So here is the challenge. You are given this code (assume jQuery included):

```
<input type=text>
<script>
    $("input").val(**YOUR PHP / JS CODE HERE**);
</script>
```

Using jQuery - and not by injecting PHP output directly into the input tag - faithfully reproduce ANY text from the database in the input tag. If the database field says `</script>`, the field should say that too. If has Chinese in it, double quotes, whatever, reproduce that too. Assume your PHP variable is called `$text`.

Here are some of my failed attempts.

1)

```
$("input").val("<?= htmlentities($text); ?>");
```

FAILURE: Reproduces character encoding exactly as is in text fields.
INPUT: `$text = "Déjà vu"`
OUTPUT: Field contains literal `d&eacute;j&agrave; vu`

2)

```
$("input").val(<?= json_encode($text); ?>);
```

This was suggested as the answer in my last question, and I naively accepted it. However...
FAILURE: `json_encode` only works with UTF-8 characters.
INPUT: `$text = "Va e de här fö frågor egentlien"`
OUTPUT: Field is blank, because `json_encode` returns `null`.

3)

```
var temp = $("<div></div>").html("<?= htmlentities($text); ?>");
$("input").val(temp.html());
```

This was my most promising solution for the weird characters, except...
FAILURE: Does not encode some characters (not sure exactly which, don't care)
INPUT: `$text = "</script> Déjà"`
OUTPUT: Field contains `&lt;/script&gt; Déjà`

4) Suggested in answers

```
$("input").val(unescape("<?= urlencode($text); ?>"));
```

FAILURE: Spaces remain encoded as +'s.

```
$("input").val(unescape(<?= rawurlencode($text); ?>"));
```

*Almost* works. All previous input succeeds, but multibyte stuff, like kanji, remain encoded. `decodeURIComponent` also doesn't like multibyte characters.

Note that for me, things like `strip_tags` are not an option. Everything must be allowed. People are authoring quizzes with this, and if someone wants to make a quiz that tests your knowledge of HTML, so be it. Also, unfortunately I cannot just inject the `htmlentities` escaped text into the value field of the input tags. These tags are generated dynamically, and I would have to totally tear down my current javascript code structure to do it that way.

I feel like I'm SOL here. Please show me how wrong I am.

### EDIT

Assume the user initally entered `</script> Déjà här fö frågor 漢字` into the db. This would be stored (you would see it in phpMyAdmin) as `</script> Déjà här fö frågor &#28450;&#23383;`

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with solution #3? Why do you care that certain characters are not encoded, as long as the browser handles them properly?

Comment: you should have not post another question if the previous was not solved...

Comment: because users will type `<script>` into the field, submit it, and it will spit `&lt;/script&gt;` back out at them. They'll be confused, and if they submit the form again like that without noticing, it will ruin their input.

Comment: Why not just use a rich edit control instead of plaintext?

Comment: Give an example of a value of `$text` for which `$("input").val(unescape(<?= rawurlencode($text); ?>"));` fails.

Comment: `$text = "</script> Déjà här fö frågor &#28450;&#23383;"`. That's what the database stores. So technically it's correct in reproducing what the db sees. But it needs to re-encode the last two multibyte characters into kanji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a "good enough" solution that you all might find interesting.

1. `utf8_encode` the string on the way into the database. This makes sure that it can be safely handled on the way out by the following steps.

2.

```
function repl($match)
{
    return "\u" . dechex($match[1]);
}

function esc($string)
{
    $s = json_encode($string);
    $s = preg_replace_callback("/&#([0-9]+);/", "repl", $s);
    return $s;
}
```

This isn't absolutely perfect, because there doesn't seem to be any way for the php to know the difference between the user typing 漢 or literally typing `&#28450;`. So if you type the latter it will become the former. But I doubt anyone will ever want to do that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode in PHP, and decode in JavaScript...

PHP's **[rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode)**:

```
echo rawurlencode("</script> Déjà");
//result: %3C%2Fscript%3E+D%C3%A9j%C3%A0
```

JavaScript's **[decodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURIComponent.asp)**:

```
var encoded = "%3C%2Fscript%3E+D%C3%A9j%C3%A0";
alert(decodeURIComponent(encoded));
//result: </script> Déjà
```

Comment: You could just use rawurlencode instead of urlencode and then you wouldn't have to replace the plus signs manually.

Comment: Nice, I tested that and it seemed to work. Simplified my answer!

Comment: Sorry, fails! With some input (including multibyte chars) javascript complains of malformed uri component.

Comment: @Tess What about converting the text to UTF-8 before encoding? You said "accurately". This gives an accurate representation of the bytestream.

Comment: If you want more/better answers to this question, you're going to have to provide unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

What encoding is your text in, if not UTF-8?  If you don't know, you don't have text, you have a byte sequence, which is much harder to faithfully represent.  If you do know, you can do something like this using the [PHP multibyte string](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension:

```
$("input").val(<?= json_encode(mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1")); ?>);
```

Here I've presumed your input is in ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1 encoding, which is a pretty common case for database strings.

**EDIT:** This is in response to the comments about a closing script tag.  I made this test file and it displays properly for me, at least in Firefox 3.6:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
</head>
<form name='foo'>
    <input name='bar' id='bar'/>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $('input').val("<\/script>");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the right answer, you need to normalise to UTF8 first and it'll work fine

Comment: i've been trying this and it still fails for closing script tags. They get turned into `<\/script>`, but that still breaks the js. Also the multibyte characters still don't get converted back. Can you explain "normalize to UTF-8"?

Comment: If I combine this answer with my #3, it doesn't break, but the script tags don't show up at all.

Comment: Does it work if you just put that in the code directly?  This works for me in Firefox in a test HTML file with jQuery 1.4.2: `$('input').val("<\/script>");` -- does that code not fill the box for you?

Comment: If I use this as is, multibyte characters are not shown correctly. Try it with the full input string I gave at the end of my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use urlencode() and urldecode().

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode)
- [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) (probably the easiest option)
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) with `ENT_QUOTES` or perhaps a combination of `htmlspecialchars` with `ENT_NOQUOTES` and [`addslashes`](http://pt2.php.net/addslashes) if you don't want your quotes to turn into HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

safe javascript escaping for ascii strings.

```
<?php
function js_encode($string)
{
    $cleaned = is_null($string) ? null : '';

    // for each letter of the string
    for ($i=0, $len = strlen($string); $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        // get ascii number
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        // if [0-9] or [A-Z] or [a-z]
        $cleaned .= (47 < $ord && $ord < 58 OR 64 < $ord && $ord < 91 OR 96 < $ord && $ord < 123)
            // use existing character
            ? $string[$i]
            // otherwise escape it
            : '\x'.dechex($ord);
    }

    return $cleaned;
}
```

for unicode text it is a little more complicated, I am going to start with this and see if I need to do the more complex version.