# How do i pass value in url?

Tags: php, sql

how do i create the url of the links? I want when users click on action it will redirect users to the action page.But i don't want to create pages for the links i have provided below.what i want to do is to display different genres type content on  the same page;

here is my html

```
<ul class="snav">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Art and Experimental</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Comedy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Crime and Mystery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Documentary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Epic and Historical</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fantasy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foreign</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Live Performances</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Musicals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Romance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Science Fiction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Special Interest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thriller</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">War</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Westerns</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (ie, `/test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2`)? That's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't very clear. Could you possible rephrase your question? Also - Giving examples of what you've already tried is always good, then people are more likely to (be able to) help you.

Comment: @admdrew no i am new to php

Comment: @PeterHamilton what i want to do is to create the genre links url dynamically.

Comment: @Sunny that was a bullshit vote but whatever.

Comment: @WillHarrison your answer was also right so does ross.but i cant accept two answer and i found ross's answer easy to understand that is why .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to use $_GET variables using PHP and have something like:

Links look like

```
<a href="?genre=action">Action</a>
```

PHP file:

```
if (isset($_GET['genre'])) {
switch ($_GET['genre']) {
   case 'action':
      echo 'something here';
      break;
   case 'horror':
      echo 'something here';
      break;

  //etc
}
}
```

or you could use jQuery to dynamically load the data into the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: well it works fine.but i am getting an undefined index error:genre.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. When working with REQUEST variables you should always preform some sort of validation to make sure they exist (at least).

Comment: well sorry i unintentionally press the button!

Comment: Haha, fair enough. No worries, dude. I just thought someone had said it was wrong or something. :p

Comment: Saying that, I think I edited it after it was downvoted...if you wouldn't mind you could you try and upvote it? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use query strings to form a url based off your base url.

```
http://domain.tld/index.php?genre=crime
```

index.php

```
if ($_GET['genre'] == 'crime') {
    // display crime genre
} else {
    // display index
}
```

You'll also want to include some validation/error checking when you're doing this.  You can check whether or not the genre param is set using [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset).  It is also important to [`escape the input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148820/escaping-output-safely-for-both-html-and-input-fields) to 'genre' so that [`injection attacks`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) are less likely.

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted, this seems to be exactly what the poster is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the links and change page content all in one go, you can try:

```
<?php
  $actions = array("Action", "Art and Experimental", "Comedy", "Crime and Mystery", "Documentary", "Drama", "Epic and Historical", "Family", "Fantasy", "Foreign", "Horror", "Live Performances", "Musicals", "Romance", "Science Fiction", "Special Interest", "Sports", "Thriller", "War", "Westerns");
?>

<ul class="snav">
<?php
foreach($actions as $action) {
    $url_token = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($action));
    echo '<li><a href="?genre=' . $url_token . '">' . $action . '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>

<?php
$genre = $_GET['genre'];

switch ($genre) {
    case 'action':
        echo 'Woo Action!';
        break;
    case 'drama':
        echo 'GASP!';
        break;
    case 'art_and_experimental':
        echo 'Weird...';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'There is no action called ' . $genre . ' :(';
}
?>
```

This will generate html of the form:

```
<ul class="snav">
    <li><a href="?genre=action">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="?genre=art_and_experimental">Art and Experimental</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: how do i redirect a user when they clicked on an image to another page?